# Squid3 Setup , No Internet Connection

Tags: http, proxy, squid

I have a problem regarding my squid setup.
The use of the proxy server will be for external clients and not local.
After I installed Squid3 and configured everything I get only " No Internet Connection" from all the ip's.
My setup has a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 subnet and at the moment just one client with an external ip .

The port 3128 is by default because there is no problem with that
I attached my config file if that helps

http://pastebin.com/r3nBnSzQ